# IPhone crashes when capturing multiple images and also slows down

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developing an application where I need to capture multiple images and store them in a folder. The application crashes when the images exceed.Also while taking images IPhone slows down a bit. Please anyone can help me with this.

code fo capturing image

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate=self;   
picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Code for adding images into file

```
NSString  *pngImagePath =
[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]
stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString
stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",imageName]];

    [dataImage writeToFile:pngImagePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Do you display the images on the screen after capturing them?

Comment: Just a common thing , are you keeping a collection with your images inside? This can be the cause of the issue, by having a collecting too big it will make your application perform poorly.

Comment: Post your code which capture and store image in the folder..

Comment: yes i display them on screen

Comment: That's the problem. You need to convert them and reduce the size of the images on the screen. Uncompressed images take amount of something like 2.5MB each one, that sit in memory.

Comment: so if i dont display them on screen will the application work fine

Comment: Yes.. see my answer below

Comment: Actually I'm uploading images on google drive. So I dont want to compress images

Comment: It's up to you :)
But the class method is for resizing images to smaller size. It actually resizes them in size and not only showing in smaller aspect.

Comment: Is ur app is ARC enabled ?>

Comment: Yes my app is ARC enabled

Answer (score 0):

Here, take this code as example to resize images before you show them on the screen:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
          scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Notice that you should also reduce the images before you save them to the disk:

```
UIImage *image = YOUR_IMAGE;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .06); // Here's the level of compression
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with @autoreleasepool once, may be its due to some memory leaks. @autoreleasepool with maintain upto some extent..

```
 @autoreleasepool
    {
      // any allocation for UIImage if u have just bring inside the autoreleasepool
        NSString  *pngImagePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
        NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString
        stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",imageName]];
        [dataImage writeToFile:pngImagePath atomically:YES];
    }
```